# copy on mouse highlight in terminal app

Tags: mouse

Is there some way to enable copying text when selecting text via the mouse in the terminal app?

The settings dialog in the terminal app only seems to provide a way to select a theme and font size.

Comment: Were you able to do this on another Linux system? If so, do you know which terminal it was?

Comment: yeah on KDE’s terminal app its a config option. I also know it from Xterm on OSX.

Comment: Correct me if I wrong, but this something different than the middle-button(scroll wheel) copy/paste function where you highlight text with the mouse and then click the middle-button.

Comment: Have you tried installing the KDE Konsole? `sudo apt install konsole`. I installed it but I'm not seeing the settings you were talking about.

Comment: Thanks @Paul the select-middle-button click sequence did it for me!

Answer (score 3):

Found solution that works in the terminal app:

System Settings -> Mouse & Touchpad -> Clicking -> Middle click paste

https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-mouse-touchpad/issues/47

Comment: Wow, how did I miss this?! Thanks so much, this should be the selected answer, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you just want to copy text after highlighting it with a mouse. Correct? You should be able to just alternate-click and select copy.

[image]

**EDIT:**
**1)** A possible solution is to use the middle-button (scroll wheel) copy/paste function. Just highlight the text with your mouse and then click the middle button (scroll wheel). It will paste what you highlighted.

**2)** Another possible solution is to install gnome-terminal and then install this patch: http://www.taika.org/~tomba/gnome-terminal/index.html
It should give you the PuTTY like function of copying just by highlighting text.

**3)** Another solution is to use the `terminator` terminal. This has the **PuTTY style paste** option built into it.

[image]

Comment: yeah .. but I would like to not have to do anything beyond selecting text .. ie. as soon as I select any text .. it should copy it to the clipboard.

Comment: OK. I understand now.  I'm not sure about the elementary OS terminal, but I think there was a way to do this in the Gnome Terminal. Is this what you were looking for?: http://www.taika.org/~tomba/gnome-terminal/index.html

Comment: I'm searching for the same solution. I'm way too used to the very convenient "copy on highlight". Any ideas?